# jQuery sticky navbar

Tags: jquery, navbar, sticky

I am trying to make a sticky navbar that sticks to the top only when it touches the top, but my jQuery code is not working.

Code(jQuery):

```
function findDistance()
{
    var distToTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var navOffset = $('#navbar').offset().top;
    var distance = (navOffset - distToTop);
    return distance;
}
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var defaultNavDist = 166;
    var distance = findDistance();
    var fixedSet = false;
    $(window).scroll(function()
    {
        if(distance < 1 && fixedSet == false)
        {
            fixedSet = true;
            $('#navbar').css('position', 'fixed');
        }
    });
});
```

Link to jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/fj10ruqs/

Comment: A JSFiddle or something similar would help to debug and offer revisions.

Comment: Here is the fiddle you asked for: http://jsfiddle.net/fj10ruqs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the window scroll handler runs, distance is not being recalculated.  You need to put `distance = findDistance();` inside the scroll handler.  You'll also probably want to add `$('#navbar').css('top', '0');` when you are fixing it to the top so that it will be at the top.

```
 $(window).scroll(function()
    {
        distance = findDistance();
        if(distance < 1 && fixedSet == false)
        {
            fixedSet = true;
            $('#navbar').css('position', 'fixed');
            $('#navbar').css('top', '0');
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, hadn't noticed that :D

Comment: Now i have another problem... If the navbar hits default dist, it should go back to it's original position... http://jsfiddle.net/fj10ruqs/1/

Comment: Ok, i figured it out. No need for more help

Comment: Once the navbar it is fixed, your `distance` variable will always be zero, so it will never be `>= defaultNavDist`.  You are not carefully walking through your logic.  Use F12 and console.log to show the variables at different locations in your code and you'll be able to find the bugs instead of relying on someone like me that is bored at work.  :)

Comment: Yeah i know, i hadn't slept very well yesterday

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it totally working for me.`

CSS

```
#navbar {
    margin-top:120px; 
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  z-index: 9999;
}

/* Navbar links */
#navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* Page content */
.content {
  padding: 16px;
}

/* The sticky class is added to the navbar with JS when it reaches its scroll position */
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%
}

/* Add some top padding to the page content to prevent sudden quick movement (as the navigation bar gets a new position at the top of the page (position:fixed and top:0) */
.sticky + .content {
  padding-top: 80px;
}
```

JS

```
// When the user scrolls the page, execute myFunction
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

// Get the navbar
var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");

// Get the offset position of the navbar
var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

// Add the sticky class to the navbar when you reach its scroll position. Remove "sticky" when you leave the scroll position
function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    navbar.classList.add("sticky")
  } else {
    navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```